# Macros to search for two values in two different columns and use it populate information in a third column

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a timesheet and I've been looking to develop a macros for the following:

- Columns 1 & 2 have the employee's first and last name.
- Column 3 has the employee number.
- Column 5 has the weekly contracted hours (already populated).
- Column 6 has the week ending date for the month (there are 4 or 5 weeks per month therefore we have 5 rows per employee).

What I am looking for is a macro button which will ask the user for the employee number, then ask the user which week ending date they would like. This should identify a single row. Based on that I would like an input box to amend the weekly number of hours in Column 5.

The timesheet will be already be populated and this function will only allow amendments to be made to the weekly hours. The reason they can't just type it in is because the cells will be locked and we don't want end users accessing them unecessarily.

Sounds long winded I know but we have approximately 800 timesheets to distribute to people with varying experience of Excel, locking all those cells prevents them from deleting data needlessly.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Revision on 14th August 2012:**

Here is the final solution to the problem I had (courtesy of Siddarth Rout), works wonderfully well and there are plenty of parameters to ensure that an absolute beginner in Excel can use it comfortably:

```
 Private Sub AmendWeeklyHoursCommandButton_Click()

 Unload AmendEmployeeUserForm

 ' Turn off screen updating to speed up macro.
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="control"

 'Find employee number
Dim EmployeeNumber As String
Dim Continue As Boolean
Dim aCell As Range

Continue = True

Do While Continue = True
 Again: EmployeeNumber = InputBox("Please enter the employee number:", "Amend the employee's weekly contracted hours")

 If StrPtr(EmployeeNumber) = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
        AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
        '~~> User pressed cancel
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '~~> User pressed OK with something filled
        If EmployeeNumber <> "" Then
            With ActiveSheet
                Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=EmployeeNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    Selection.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=EmployeeNumber
                    Continue = False
                'If an invalid entry is entered
                Else
                    If MsgBox("You entered an invalid employee number - Try again?", _
                    vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Search Again?") = vbYes Then GoTo Again
                    If vbNo Then Range("G6").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
                    AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
                    Exit Sub

                End If
            End With
        '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
        Else
            MsgBox "You didn't enter a value. Please enter the employee number or press cancel."
            Continue = True
        End If
    End If
Loop


 'Find Week Ending Date
Dim WeekEnding As String
Dim Continue1 As Boolean
Dim bCell As Range

Continue1 = True

Do While Continue1 = True
 Again1:        WeekEnding = InputBox("Please enter the week ending date:", "Amend the employee's weekly contracted hours")

 If StrPtr(WeekEnding) = 0 Then
        '~~> User pressed cancel
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Range("G6").Select
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
        AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '~~> User pressed OK with something filled
        If WeekEnding <> "" Then
            With ActiveSheet
                Set bCell = .Columns(6).Find(What:=WeekEnding, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not bCell Is Nothing Then
                    Selection.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=WeekEnding
                    Continue1 = False
                Else
                'If an invalid entry is entered
                    If MsgBox("You entered an invalid week ending date - Try again?", _
                    vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Search again?") = vbYes Then GoTo Again1
                    If vbNo Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
                    Range("G6").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
                    AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
                    Exit Sub

                End If
            End With
        Else
            '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
            MsgBox "You didn't enter a value. Please enter the week ending date or press cancel."
            Continue1 = True
        End If
    End If
Loop

 'Control + home
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter
    Set Rng = .Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Range.Rows.Count - 1)
    Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Select
End With

 'Select hours column
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Activate

 'Enter hours
 Dim NewHours As String
 Dim Continue2 As Boolean

 Continue2 = True

Do While Continue2 = True
NewHours = InputBox("Please enter the new hours:", "Enter New Contracted Hours")

 If StrPtr(NewHours) = 0 Then
        '~~> User pressed cancel
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Range("G6").Select
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
        AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
        Exit Sub

        'User pressed OK WITH something filled
        ElseIf NewHours <> "" Then
        ActiveCell = NewHours
        Continue2 = False
    Else
        '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a value. Please enter the number of hours or press cancel."
        Continue2 = True
End If
 Loop

'Completion message
MsgBox "You have successfully amended the details for " & aCell.Offset(0, -1).Value     & " " & aCell.Offset(0, -2).Value

'Show all data
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 Range("G6").Select

 End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Sam - your question is just a set of requirements.  What **specifically** are you having a problem with?

Comment: Please see the revised description, cheers guys

Comment: Came up with a solution which filtered the information I needed, then navigated to the cell I wanted to amend, used an input value code to enter the new data

Comment: @Asim What was your solution? You should post that code here as an answer, then accept it so that others may find it more easily in the future.

Comment: Sorry solution now added. How do I accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full answer:

```
Private Sub AmendWeeklyHoursCommandButton_Click()

Unload AmendEmployeeUserForm

 ' Turn off screen updating to speed up macro.
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="control"

 'Find employee number
 Dim EmployeeNumber As String
 Dim Continue As Boolean
 Dim aCell As Range

 Continue = True

 Do While Continue = True
  Again: EmployeeNumber = InputBox("Please enter the employee number:", "Amend the      employee's weekly contracted hours")

  If StrPtr(EmployeeNumber) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
    AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
    '~~> User pressed cancel
    Exit Sub
Else
    '~~> User pressed OK with something filled
    If EmployeeNumber <> "" Then
        With ActiveSheet
            Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=EmployeeNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                Selection.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=EmployeeNumber
                Continue = False
            'If an invalid entry is entered
            Else
                If MsgBox("You entered an invalid employee number - Try again?", _
                vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Search Again?") = vbYes Then GoTo Again
                If vbNo Then Range("G6").Select
                ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
                AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
                Exit Sub

            End If
        End With
    '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
    Else
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a value. Please enter the employee number or press cancel."
        Continue = True
    End If
End If
 Loop


 'Find Week Ending Date
 Dim WeekEnding As String
 Dim Continue1 As Boolean
 Dim bCell As Range

 Continue1 = True

 Do While Continue1 = True
 Again1:        WeekEnding = InputBox("Please enter the week ending date:", "Amend the employee's weekly contracted hours")

 If StrPtr(WeekEnding) = 0 Then
    '~~> User pressed cancel
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Range("G6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
    AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
    Exit Sub
Else
    '~~> User pressed OK with something filled
    If WeekEnding <> "" Then
        With ActiveSheet
            Set bCell = .Columns(6).Find(What:=WeekEnding, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not bCell Is Nothing Then
                Selection.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=WeekEnding
                Continue1 = False
            Else
            'If an invalid entry is entered
                If MsgBox("You entered an invalid week ending date - Try again?", _
                vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Search again?") = vbYes Then GoTo Again1
                If vbNo Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
                Range("G6").Select
                ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
                AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
                Exit Sub

            End If
        End With
    Else
        '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a value. Please enter the week ending date or press cancel."
        Continue1 = True
    End If
End If
 Loop

 'Control + home
 Dim Rng As Range
 With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter
Set Rng = .Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Range.Rows.Count - 1)
Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Select
 End With

 'Select hours column
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Activate

 'Enter hours
 Dim NewHours As String
 Dim Continue2 As Boolean

 Continue2 = True

 Do While Continue2 = True
 NewHours = InputBox("Please enter the new hours:", "Enter New Contracted Hours")

 If StrPtr(NewHours) = 0 Then
    '~~> User pressed cancel
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Range("G6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"
    AmendEmployeeUserForm.Show
    Exit Sub

    'User pressed OK WITH something filled
    ElseIf NewHours <> "" Then
    ActiveCell = NewHours
    Continue2 = False
Else
    '~~> User pressed OK WITHOUT anything filled
    MsgBox "You didn't enter a value. Please enter the number of hours or press cancel."
    Continue2 = True
 End If
 Loop

 'Completion message
 MsgBox "You have successfully amended the details for " & aCell.Offset(0, -1).Value     & " " & aCell.Offset(0, -2).Value

 'Show all data
 ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="control"

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 Range("G6").Select

 End Sub
```